# React: function sending infinity GET requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Component that fetches data from a server on getConvForNum, but somehow it enters an infinite loop.
Even if i keep only render() and this function it keep sending GET requests to server.

OpentTickets.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Button, Accordion, Card, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        people: [],
        customer_pn: '',
        date: '',
        conversation: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`/getongoing?limit=10`)
            .then(res => {
                const people = res.data;
                this.setState({people});
            });
    }

    getConvForNum(phone_nm) {
        axios.get('/getconvfornum?customer_number=' + phone_nm.slice(1)).then(res => {
            const conversation = res.data;
            this.setState({conversation})
        });
        return (
            this.state.conversation.map(message =>
                <div>
                    <p>{message.from}</p>
                    <p>{message.body}</p>

                </div>
            )

        )
    }

    render() {
        return (

            this.state.people.map(person =>
                <>
                    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Header>
                                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="button" eventKey="0">
                                    Converstaion random
                                </Accordion.Toggle>
                                Phone number: {person}
                            </Card.Header>
                            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                                <Card.Body>
                                    {this.getConvForNum(person)}
                                    <Form.Control type = 'text'/>
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Accordion.Collapse>
                        </Card>
                    </Accordion>
                </>
            )

        )
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import {push as Menu} from 'react-burger-menu'
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import AuthenticatedComponent from "./AuthenticatedComponent";
import Login from "./Login";
import OpenTickets from "./OpenTickets";
import ExportToLog from "./ExportToLog";
import LogOut from "./LogOut";
import '../css/slideBarNav.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../css/style.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <>
                        <Menu className='navBar'>
                            <NavLink exact to="/"  className='menu-item' activeClassName='active'>Home</NavLink>

                            <NavLink to="/opentickets" className='menu-item' activeClassName='active'>Open Tickets</NavLink>

                            <NavLink to="/exportlog" className='menu-item' activeClassName='active'>Export Log</NavLink>

                            <NavLink to ='/logout' className='menu-item'>Log Out</NavLink>
                        </Menu>
                        <AuthenticatedComponent>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard}/>
                            <Route path="/opentickets" component={OpenTickets}/>
                            <Route path="/exportlog" component={ExportToLog}/>
                            <Route path='/logout' component={LogOut}/>
                        </AuthenticatedComponent>
                    </>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Not sure what cause this infinity loop
I'm new in react so probably i just didn't understand something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the render function you have the `getConvForNum(person)` call which will do the get request and set the state,
`SetState` will trigger render function call, render will call `getConvForNum(person)` again and so on..

You can compare `this.state.conversation` to the new returned value from the get call before setting state to avoid the infinite calls

Comment: Before this.setState({conversation}) call you should check if conversation array changed